# Bulk Insert does not insert data

Tags: sql-server, insert, bulk

I want to perform a Bulk Insert for data I get via Stream. Here I get Survey data where each row are the information and answers of a person. I consumed the stream via .net and saved the data row by row each ending with a vblf (I checked if this exist via Word and could see that after each dataset there is a new line). The data are comma separated. First off I created a table with 1000 columns, since I do not know yet how many data will come in but for sure there is not dataset longer than 500 yet and even in the future it will definitly not get longer than 1000 and if so, I can extend the table. Here the Table I created:

[image]

The first two datasets looks like this:

```
"4482359","12526","2014 Company","upload by","new upload","Anonymous","User","anonymous@company.org","","222.222.222.222","1449772662000","undefined","","951071","2015","","2","3","1","5","1","1","3","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","1","3","3","3","3","1","2","3","1","3","5","1","","Here ppl can type in some text.","1"
"4482360","12526","2014 Company","upload by","new upload","Anonymous","User","anonymous@company.org","","222.222.222.222","1449772662000","undefined","","951071","2015","","2","5","1","","2","2","3","4","3","1","4","4","4","4","3","3","","4","3","1","4","3","1","4","4","4","3","3","4","4","4","4","3","4","4","4","4","4","4","5","2","3","4","1","3","2","2","5","1","3","","2","","","2"
```

Now I want to do a Bulk Insert using this command:

```
USE MyDatabase 
BULK INSERT insert_Table FROM 'C:\new.txt'
With (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

The command runs through and does not thow an error but I get the message `0 rows affected` and there is no data in the datatable. Does anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: A table with 1000 columns indicates to me that you need to think about designing it in a different way.

Comment: You can try `ROWTERMINATOR = 0x0a`; I've had trouble with `\n`, it got replaced with `\r\n`.

Comment: I deleted the first row (ID) and Firstrow=2 and tried \r\n, \n and 0x0a. Now it insertes everything into one row. I exchanged vblf with environment.newline in .net but still, everything into one row.

Comment: ID is the first column, not a row. If you're confusing rows with columns it may get tricky to get an answer.

Comment: You are right. I was confused. sorry